# Ideas for increasing efficiency on data heavy site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures

I am working on a site for a client and am trying to be more efficient in how I pull down their sales data. My original solution turned into a spaghetti mess of custom SQL queries that feels why too hack-y. Next I tried to write a wrapper class (SalesCalculator) that would pull down all the relevant sales records and attempt to process them in Ruby, but when we are talking about 30,000+ records it greatly hurts performance, to the point that even caching would be potentially annoying (we are talking >10s page loads).

I also tried just building a query for eac

I guess my overall goal is to simplify my interactions with the data so that I can keep a consistent interface. Here are a couple of things that I would typically doing on any given page:

- total revenue of sales for each year over a 3 year period
- same as above, but broken into 5 or so departments
- total revenue by month for department/employee (for current and previous year)
- etc.

So my question would be what suggestions/examples do you guys have of doing similar things with large datasets?

Comment: 30k records shouldn't really hurt performance in any DBMS that I know of (or in Ruby, for that matter). I'd advise you to give us some examples of what you are doing, perhaps an outline of the database layout and some of your slowest queries, so we can figure out what is really going wrong there.

Comment: Yeah no problem! Essentially, a sales invoice record would have: date, amount, tonnage, employee_id, customer_id, product_id. 

I wanted to build a query-like interface that would let me grab all the records I needed and then whittle them down for various subsets, i.e. total sales for each year in the data set for a certain department. I am able to do these things in SQL, but the idea was to migrate the logic to ruby so I'd have more control and flexibility, but I fear the problem was the array of 30,000+ AR objects being iterated through at least 15 times (once for each of 3 years, per dept).

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the page to give you an idea. I removed the actual sales numbers, but basically filling in the boxes. http://s3.noahhendrix.com/system/1296111185_Screen%20shot%202011-01-27%20at%2012.51.48%20AM.png

Comment: I'm all for having my business logic in Ruby but those aggregations I would gladly hand over to the database.

Answer (score 3):

30k is nothing. even for SQLite database.

your problem is this: 30,000+ AR objects being iterated through at least 15 times - don't do it. that's bad idea and bad design and it's just bad from every perspective.

you already have a date field in your table, why not using WHERE YEAR(date)=2011 ? you can add department column into database. you can add index on certain fields to increase query performance. you can do ton of things to narrow down your search and have only AR objects you really need.

downloading your whole database into 30k AR objects is the last thing you want to do and i can't imagine what would be the problem to require solution like that.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're using your Database as a filesystem, and using Ruby via Rails to do the heavy lifting of building your report - I'd go back to using SQL.

Test your queries, and *add indexes* as appropriate, and you should be able to get your page load time right down.

Comment: I agree. Let SQL sum things for you. Also depending on your database schema you might have problems with selecting the datasets. Do know what is taking most time - SQL or ruby?

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the database do the calculations. It's many times faster than calculating the totals in ruby. Make sure you have the necessairy indexes.

Doing native queries in rails:

```
class Sales

  # Other code

  def self.totals (group_by, where, ...)
    # Build the query depending of the parameters
    sql = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM sales ... " 
    # Execute the query
    result = connection.execute(sql) 
    # when using mysql result will be a Mysql::Result object
    # Finally you can wrap the totals in a nice hash
    data = {}
    result.each_hash do |row|
      data[row['col']] = row['other_col']
    end
    data
  end
```

This allows querying by calling `Sales.totals(..)`.

If you want to query from an other class, just use `Sales.connection.execute(sql)`

Mysql api: http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `named_scope`'s might be the way to go you can feed them with parameters describing how you want to filter the data (let the database do the heavy lifting).

If this isn't possible there is always `find_each(:batch => 1000)` which will grab 1000 records at a time.